# Copy a note from a task to a case

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a manually invoked process which is tied to the account entity. This process has a number of steps. One of the first steps is to create a task and assign it to someone. It's expected that this person will add some notes and complete the task.

Further down the process, I have a step to create a service case. After this is created, I want to copy the note(s) from the task above to the newly created service case.

I have created a custom workflow activity to try and accomplish this. I have gotten as far as deploying it and using it within my process without any errors and it does copy content into the notes field of the service case, however it copies the title of the task, not the note content and I can't quite fathom out why.

```
public class CopyNotes : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        //Create the context
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        //get the notes associated with the source entity
        Guid copyFromId = CopyFrom.Get(executionContext).Id;
        Guid copyToId = CopyTo.Get(executionContext).Id;

        EntityCollection copyFromNotes = RetrieveNotes(service, copyFromId);

        if (copyFromNotes.Entities.Any())
        {
            foreach (Entity e in copyFromNotes.Entities)
            {
                Entity newNote = new Entity("annotation");
                newNote.Attributes["subject"] = e.Attributes["subject"];
                newNote.Attributes["notetext"] = e.Attributes["notetext"];
                newNote.Attributes["objectid"] = new EntityReference() { Id = copyToId, LogicalName = CopyTo.Get(executionContext).LogicalName };
            }
        }
    }

    private EntityCollection RetrieveNotes(IOrganizationService service, Guid relatedObject)
    {

        ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
        condition.AttributeName = "objectid";
        condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
        condition.Values.Add(relatedObject.ToString());

        ColumnSet columns = new ColumnSet("subject", "notetext");

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.ColumnSet = columns;
        query.EntityName = "annotation";
        query.Criteria.AddCondition(condition);

        EntityCollection results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        return results;

    }

    [RequiredArgument]
    [ReferenceTarget("task")]
    [Input("Copy notes from item")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> CopyFrom { get; set; }

    [RequiredArgument]
    [ReferenceTarget("incident")]
    [Input("Copy notes to item")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> CopyTo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to actually create the newNote after defining it.

```
foreach (Entity e in copyFromNotes.Entities)
{
     Entity newNote = new Entity("annotation");
     newNote.Attributes["subject"] = e.Attributes["subject"];
     newNote.Attributes["notetext"] = e.Attributes["notetext"];
     newNote.Attributes["objectid"] = new EntityReference() { Id = copyToId, LogicalName = CopyTo.Get(executionContext).LogicalName };
     service.Create(newNote);
}
```

Once I did that your code worked just fine creating a new note with both the title and note text.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a standard workflow, if Async creation is fast enough.

Andreas